# Python Numba: jitting functions stored in a class

Tags: python, numba, python-class

I am trying to combine and jit functions that are stored in a class. The functions themselves are jitted, but jitting the function that combines these fails on the error:

```py
Untyped global name 'self': Cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.a_class'>
```

MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


class a_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []

    def add_random_function(self):
        power = np.random.random()

        @njit
        def fn(x):
            return x**power
        self.functions.append(fn)

    def jit_functions(self):
        @njit
        def jitted_sum(x):
            ans = 0
            for function in self.functions:
                ans += function(x)
            return ans
        self.jitted_sum = jitted_sum


my_class = a_class()
my_class.add_random_function()
my_class.add_random_function()
my_class.jit_functions()
my_class.jitted_sum(2)
```

The functions are much more computationally heavy than in this example, and they and their combination would benefit from being jitted.

Is there a way to collect these functions in a class, and generate a new function from them, or any other workaround that allows me to compile a function that uses other functions, and how can I store them? (the functions will be defined by parameters that are attributes of the class instance)

Error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'self': Cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.a_class'>

File "<ipython-input-8-52f3da1fe6b5>", line 23:
        def jitted_sum(x):
            <source elided>
            ans = 0
            for function in self.functions:
            ^
```